# google analytics shorturlclicks vs longurlclicks

Tags: google-analytics-api

I don't understand what is **longUrlClicks** parameter in google analytics url-shortener's shortURL history: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#url_analytics

If it represents the number of clicks on this url then how does google know it? I can assume that google counts only clicks that were made from one of google subdomains... am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

analytics.allTime.shortUrlClicks = Number of clicks on this short URL.

analytics.allTime.longUrlClicks = Number of clicks on all goo.gl short URLs pointing to this long URL.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url

Comment: Just as a note : 
I recently wondered  how could there be different short urls pointing to the same URL. It happens when different users are creating a short link to the same Url.